# How to create copy of a view in a worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, view

i want to create copy of a view in background. I know it is possible to create a view in      background by using Looper.prepare() inside rum method of thread, and i have tested it. But i am not able to get all properties/attributes of original view like scroll position etc for making the exact copy.
Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need an exact copy?

Comment: @FD_ actually i want to take screenshots of an imageview by applying different bitmaps in background, so user does not have to wait for this screen.